# SQL to Cosmos DB migration, do we need multiple containers as different tables in SQL?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are planning to SQL DB migration to Cosmos DB, as I am new in cosmos I am confused about container.
Do we need to take one container for each table or one container is sufficient for all table data ? Suppose we are taking multiple container can we communicate different containers through Store Procedure?

Comment: Typically the migration doesn't just reproduce the relational model in Cosmos. You need to look at how to represent your data in the document model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be successful here you need to understand how to model data and select a partition key in Cosmos DB. The concepts are very new and different than in a relational database. I would encourage you to read up on the differences as this has a huge impact on performance and cost in this type of database. This content will provide you with a solid understanding of how to design an efficient database that will scale:

(Note: have updated this answer to include more/better content given this answer is gaining traction)

Articles:

- [Understanding the differences between NoSQL and relational databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/relational-nosql)
- [Data modeling in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/modeling-data)
- [How to model and partition data on Azure Cosmos DB using a real-world example](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-model-partition-example)

Videos:

- [Modeling and Partitioning - 2 min intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOWa8ecFo88)
- [How to model and partition data in Cosmos DB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvQEG52eVrI) - This takes adventure works and remodels it for NoSQL
- [Data Modeling in Azure Cosmos DB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5rRGlKxNtk) - This talks about modeling a book store scenario

Microsoft Learn Labs: (Essentially are HOL's for the second video above)

- [Model and Partition your data in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/model-partition-data-azure-cosmos-db/)
- [Advanced modeling patterns for Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/advanced-modeling-patterns-azure-cosmos-db/)

GitHub Repo:

- [Cosmic Works](https://github.com/AzureCosmosDB/CosmicWorks) - this is the code and data set for the adventure works talk above

Modeling in Cosmos DB requires you understand your data access patterns, how do I write data, read it and how often for each.

After you have an initial design you will need to test it and measure RU/s consumption to ensure you are fairly well optimized. It doesn't need to be perfect but you should know the answer to whether any cross-partition queries are better served by using ChangeFeed and writing data into another container with a separate partition key.

There are lots of concepts to understand. I know it's a common refrain but I definitely encourage you to read the docs on Cosmos before getting in too deep.

Comment: With links it's important to summarize the information that you feel is important in case the link breaks. Links rot over time and eventually break, and when you do the answer won't make sense without that summarizing information.

Comment: Links to Azure docs should never break. We're not allowed to change the URL for a doc without a redirect to its functional equivalent. thanks.

Comment: "Should". However servers crash, network connectivity can go down, routes go wonky, etc. Here's the reasoning: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/153968. Do what you will with it.